# Fatest way to insert data in Sql Server CE

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, compact-framework, sqlcedatareader

I have been working on *C# Compact Framework 4.0* for my product.

I have an server and an mobile and i have to synchronize all the data from the server to my mobile device .

Usually around 6000 entries will be inserted into my mobile device on  an single table .

Now i use table direct with index name of the table specified .

It takes around 55 sec for 6000 entries.

Is there an faster way to insert ??

```
SqlCeCommand cmdItem = conn.CreateCommand();
SqlCeResultSet rsItem;
cmdItem.CommandText = "item_info";
cmdItem.IndexName = "PK_item_info";
cmdItem.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
rsItem = cmdItem.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable | ResultSetOptions.Scrollable);
while(reader.read()){

    SqlCeUpdatableRecord recItem = rsItem.CreateRecord();
    recItem.SetString(1, cmdItem.SerialNo);
    recItem.SetInt32(10, 0);
    rsItem.Insert(recItem);  

}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you've shared your current code

Comment: Well, hard to say without seeing your code, but keeping the connection open and specifying the data type explicitly when adding parameters to your SQL commands are two things that can influence speed. Otherwise, well, it's a mobile device and the mobile SQL Server. Don't expect miracles to happen in terms of speed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove " | ResultSetOptions.Scrollable"

And move the line:

```
SqlCeUpdatableRecord recItem = rsItem.CreateRecord();
```

Above the while loop.

```
var cmdItem = conn.CreateCommand();
cmdItem.CommandText = "item_info";
cmdItem.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
var rsItem = cmdItem.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable);
var recItem = rsItem.CreateRecord();
while(reader.read())
{        
    recItem.SetString(1, cmdItem.SerialNo);
    recItem.SetInt32(10, 0);
    rsItem.Insert(recItem);
}
```

Comment: What about the indexName ?? WIll using index name increase perfomance ??

Comment: Nope, it is not used at all (Index name is used when using Seek and SetRange)

Comment: I get a speed of 109 rows per second approx . Before am getting about 95 rows per second approx . Any other methodologies ?? I would be great if i get about 130 rows per second approx.

Comment: So it is faster now? Make sure all data types are the smallest size possible, You could experiment with dropping and recreating indexes. Look at using a faster disk (maybe fast SD Card?)

Comment: Too many indexes will slow down the insertion process. Maybe there are indexes you don't need or that you can optimize?

Answer (score 0):

Using this library you can use `SqlBulkCopy` ([SQLBulkCopy Class (Microsoft website)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.100).aspx%20SQLBulkCopy%20(MS))) with your SQL Server CE database.

[Library which supports SQL Server CE](http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/)